# Do penalties from wounds and fatigue stack?

Tags: savage-worlds

If a character is wounded and takes a level of fatigue do the penalties stack?  For example does a character with one wound and is also fatigued take a -2 penalty to all trait rolls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, penalties from wounds and fatigue stack. See [here](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39093&highlight=wounds%20fatigue) for official confirmation of this.

Comment: Also if you are playing *Realms of Cthulhu*, you get an additional track for Sanity, and penalties for it also stack with penalties gained from the Wound and Fatigue tracks.